# Getting error trying to load json from javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ag-grid

I'm having some problem with my javascript. I'm trying to load json array to ag-grid like this and the below works fine because I'm simply loading json from a json file:

```
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', '../dist/output.json');
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
            var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);


            function isNumeric(n) { 
                return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
            }

            var parsedData = httpResult.map(function(obj) {
                return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
                    var value = obj[key];
                    memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value) : value;

                    return memo;
                }, {})
            })
```

But, when I do it in the following way (i.e., getting the json array from a jsp, console.log(jsonArray) displays fine, but I get error :

```
var jsonArray = document.getElementById("jsonArray");
        console.log(jsonArray);
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', jsonArray);
        httpRequest.send();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
                var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);


                function isNumeric(n) { 
                    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
                }

                var parsedData = httpResult.map(function(obj) {
                    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
                        var value = obj[key];
                        memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value) : value;

                        return memo;
                    }, {})
                })
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How to change the first code so that I can correctly read from jsonArray, which has all the json data.

UPDATE:

jsonArray is the following from the jsp:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(orderDetailsList1);

<input type="hidden" value="<%out.println(jsonArray);%>" id="jsonArray"/>
```

Comment: Why? Your URL is wrong. How to fix? Figure out the proper URL.

Comment: What is the `#jsonArray` element?

Comment: @MarcB Which URL?

Comment: Heh You want to open DOM element? httpRequest.open('GET', jsonArray); jsonArray is DOM element from html. Crazy idea.

Comment: you need a URL, if `jsonArray` contains the URL then you have to extract that text...

Comment: You're doing an AJAX request, which is just a plain http request, and the url you're requesting doesn't exist, so you get a 404.

Comment: @Gothdo I updated my question. jsonArray is coming from jsp

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL My question is how to use jsonArray, in place of '../dist/output.json'. Change that code to what?

Comment: @Shek you are doing`var jsonArray = document.getElementById("jsonArray");` and then sending that DOM element as URL... does that DOM element contain URLs? if it does, what type of element is it? if it contains just one URL, then read the property or attribute that contain the TEXT URL and use it in your request, if it contains more than one then loop through them and generate as many requests as needed, remember you can see your project and know what you need, we are just guessing from the little piece of code you paste...

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL jsonArray just contains json data. [{"COMPLIANCE_ID":"1/FIRST/US/191CC2/20160914/pWMzecP/1","TOLERANCE":null,"WEIGHTED_ARR_LAST_SLP":"0","SLIPPAGE_INTERVAL_VWAP_BPS":"0.0000","ROOT_ORDER_ID":"86543320118214","ENTERING_TRADER":"duffy_dma2","SECURITY_ID":"SPY.P","ARRIVAL_MID_PX":"213.1800","WEIGHTED_ARR_SLP":"0","AVG_PX":"213.1800","ORDER_CCY":"USD","LEAVES_QTY":"0","WEIGHT":"0.023485837736291773","INITIATING_TRADER":null,"PARTICIPATION_RATE":"0E-12","LOCAL_REF_END_TIME":"2016-09-14}]

Comment: But now I understand var jsonArray = document.getElementById("jsonArray"); is getting null value only from the jsp. However it's not null in the jsp. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonArray` is a DOM object. To access its `value` attribute use the `value` property:

```
httpRequest.open('GET', jsonArray.value);
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'm getting null value, I don't know why jsonArray is being passed as null from jsp to the js file.